# Selenium webdriver can't locate element (it's not hidden, it's not within subframe)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to interact with a page that contains the following html code:

```
 <a data-refineby="customDateRange" class="toggleControl flushToggleControl navToggleControl">Specific Dates</a>
        <div class="navTabDropDown customDateFilter">
            <form>
                <div>
                    <span class="dateLabel">From:</span>
                    <input type="text" name="fromMonth" class="month" id="fromMonth" value="MM" maxlength="2" /> / 
                    <input type="text" name="fromDay" class="day" id="fromDay" value="DD" maxlength="2" /> / 
                    <input type="text" name="fromYear" class="year" id="fromYear" value="YYYY" maxlength="4" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="dateLabel">To:</span>
                    <input type="text" name="toMonth" class="month" id="toMonth" value="MM" maxlength="2" /> / 
                    <input type="text" name="toDay" class="day" id="toDay" value="DD" maxlength="2" /> / 
                    <input type="text" name="toYear" class="year" id="toYear" value="YYYY" maxlength="4" />
                </div>
                <div class="customFilterFooter">
                    <a class="applyCustomFilter">Refine Search</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Here's the (Python) code I'm using:

```
# import selenium, start webdriver, etc

browser.find_element_by_id("newSearchQueryTop").send_keys("foo")
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button.button").click()
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Specific Dates").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("fromMonth").send_keys("01")
browser.find_element_by_id("fromDay").send_keys("01")
browser.find_element_by_id("fromYear").send_keys("1992")
browser.find_element_by_id("toMonth").send_keys("12")
browser.find_element_by_id("toDay").send_keys("31")
browser.find_element_by_id("toYear").send_keys("1992")
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Refine Search").click()
```

The webdriver fills out the day/month/year fields correctly, but then it fails to locate the "Refine Search" button. Here's what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nyt.py", line 170, in <module>
    nyt(1, years1, 1, path)
  File "nyt.py", line 149, in nyt
    browser.find_element_by_link_text("Refine Search").click()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 246, in find_element_by_link_text
    return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 680, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Refine Search"}' ; Stacktrace: 
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/CQ/CQ1pELFuECu0jHex28Y-tU+++TI/-Tmp-/tmpOR8AB5/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8899)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///var/folders/CQ/CQ1pELFuECu0jHex28Y-tU+++TI/-Tmp-/tmpOR8AB5/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:396)
```

The "Refine Search" button is not within a subframe and it is not hidden, so I don't understand why the webdriver can't find it. I tried `time.sleep(30)` but that didn't change anything. Any thoughts?

(Mac OS X 10.6.8, Python 2.7.5, Selenium 2.35, Firefox 23.01)

Comment: Do you want work around then I can give you,to make it work... tell me. when things doesn't work..go for other way.. :) If you want let me know..

Comment: Whatever gets the job done, Babai!

Comment: Thank you for the code, Babai. Alas, the website is down right now. As soon as it is operational again I'll try your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='applyCustomFilter' and text() = 'Refine Search']").click()
```

[**`XPATH Tester`**](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22navTabDropDown%20customDateFilter%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cform%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20class%3D%22dateLabel%22%3EFrom%3A%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20name%3D%22fromMonth%22%20class%3D%22month%22%20id%3D%22fromMonth%22%20value%3D%22MM%22%20maxlength%3D%222%22%20%2F%3E%20%2F%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20name%3D%22fromDay%22%20class%3D%22day%22%20id%3D%22fromDay%22%20value%3D%22DD%22%20maxlength%3D%222%22%20%2F%3E%20%2F%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20name%3D%22fromYear%22%20class%3D%22year%22%20id%3D%22fromYear%22%20value%3D%22YYYY%22%20maxlength%3D%224%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20class%3D%22dateLabel%22%3ETo%3A%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20name%3D%22toMonth%22%20class%3D%22month%22%20id%3D%22toMonth%22%20value%3D%22MM%22%20maxlength%3D%222%22%20%2F%3E%20%2F%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20name%3D%22toDay%22%20class%3D%22day%22%20id%3D%22toDay%22%20value%3D%22DD%22%20maxlength%3D%222%22%20%2F%3E%20%2F%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20name%3D%22toYear%22%20class%3D%22year%22%20id%3D%22toYear%22%20value%3D%22YYYY%22%20maxlength%3D%224%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22customFilterFooter%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20class%3D%22applyCustomFilter%22%3ERefine%20Search%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fform%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Fa%5B%40class%3D%27applyCustomFilter%27%20and%20text%28%29%20%3D%20%27Refine%20Search%27%5D&=%2F%2Fa%5B%40class%3D%27applyCustomFilter%27%20and%20text%28%29%20%3D%20%27Refine%20Search%27%5D&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=html&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath)